# AtomエディタでIDEの様にステップ実行によるデバッグを行うことは可能か

Tags: python3, atom-editor

- **環境**
  OS：Windows10
  言語：Python3
  エディタ：Atom(1.34.0)
  Atom上でのデバッガパッケージ：atom-runner(2.7.1)
- **やりたいこと**
  Pythonをデバッグする際、一行ずつデバッグするステップ実行を行いたいのですが
  何かしらのデバッガパッケージ（atom-runnerなど）＋ショートカットキーでステップ実行できないでしょうか。
  （パッケージはatom-runnerにはこだわりません）

  なお、コード内の処理を止めたい箇所に以下のデバッグ用コードを記述するデバッグ方法は把握しています。

  `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: 関連 (Stack Overflow 上の類似質問です): ["Debugging python in Atom?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41539235/5989200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分も同様の疑問にあたり、調べてみましたが
よくあるデバッガのような動作をさせる方法は見つかりませんでした。

簡単な操作でブレークポイントを設定してデバッグしたかったので、現在はVSCodeを使用しています。

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありません。ありがとうございます。わたしは結局、セル単位で実行できるJupyter Notebookを開発環境としました。